# Get span value inside h1 by referring to h1 id

Tags: javascript

I want to get the text value (QCD Automotive) in this following HTML tag but can't:

```
<h1 class="_58gi" id="pages_name"><span>QCD Automotive</span><span class="_5rqt"><span class="_5rqu"></span></span></h1>
```

I've tried this so far, but it doesn't seem to be working. What am I doing wrong?

```
pageName = document.GetElementById("pages_name").GetElementByTagName("span").innerText
```

Comment: let me guess... `GetElementById` is not defined? :)

Comment: Seems to have syntax error, it should be document.getElementById("pages_name")  instead of document.GetElementById("pages_name")

Comment: `document.querySelector('#pages_name span').textContent;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just call wrong function by case-sensitve, your statment should be like this:

```
pageName = document.getElementById("pages_name").innerText
```

use `getElementById()` instead of `GetElementById()`
and `getElementByTagsName()` instead of `.GetElementByTagName()`.

*Notice:* `document.getElementByTagsName()` return array of elements, so if you want to use, you have to access via array index: `result[0]`.

In your case, just get `innerText` from element H1, no need to go to insides element.

Answer (score 3):

Its not `GetElementById` just use `getElementById`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution using Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //For everything in the first span, use the code below
  alert($("#pages_name").first().text());
  //If you want every text in the tag, use the code below
  alert($("#pages_name").text());
});
```

Here is a link to the [working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/P75JQyyCMNYoXHcBOeJm?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the first span value, use firstChild

```
document.getElementById("pages_name").firstChild.span
```

OR

use children

```
document.getElementById("pages_name").children[0].innerHTML
```

**Note:** children[0] is the first element in the pages_name div.

Answer (score 1):

(your browser's debugger should tell you that ) .getElementByTagName does not exist.

of course
    .getElementsByTagName
does exist : mind the ***'s'*** in Element**s**. You'll get an HTMLNodeCollection, which looks like an array but is not quite it. [More on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName)

It has a property named length and all indices are numerical, so you can iterate over it with

```
for(i=0;i<yourcollection.length;i++)
```

or with the silly looking construct :

```
[].forEach.call(yourCollection, function(item,index){
    //whatever has to be done on each item
}
```

And remember : MDN is your friend !

Answer (score 1):

try this

`pageName = document.getElementById("pages_name").getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerText`